# LINE Login failed to get access token

Tags: javascript, access-token

I am trying to create a LINE login authentication function on my web. The problem I am encountering is that I kept receiving error 400, a bad request which may have something to do with the parameter I've put in.

Here is my code,

```
    fetch('https://api.line.me/v2/oauth/accessToken', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          client_id: 'my_id',
          client_secret: 'my_client_secret',
          code: code,
          redirect_uri: 'the link direct to'
        })
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

I followed the reference from LINE, https://developers.line.me/web-api/managing-access-tokens and put in the parameter it asked for, but I kept having the same error.

Tried with postman and got the same error

I am not sure which part I did wrong. Would someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you meant that postman worked but not the code?

Comment: Yes. Postman did give me the result. When I use the code above, I get 400 (bad request)

Comment: Care to share with us the inputs for your postman query? E.g The Header and body. When you get http 400, is there other error messages in the response that can possibly be helpful? e.g. `JSON.stringify(response)` it

Comment: POST https://api.line.me/v2/oauth/accessToken 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: This is the only error message shows up.
Also, I take it back. I actually tried postman again and it's giving me the same error.
I guess I was trying with the api.line.me/v1/oauth/accessToken link which gives me the output, but v1 is deprecated according to the document.

Comment: {
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "some parameters missed or invalid"
}
This is what I've got in postman

Comment: You seem to have the correct parameters in the header and body. Maybe try doing a Curl Post and see if that makes any difference? I haven't tried authenticating oauth2 with LineCorp's API before. So can't really tell how it works.

Comment: There you go. Since your parameters are correct then it must be the values been invalid. I don't think there is any chance i can help.

Comment: Thank you Samuel. I will try Curl Post.

Comment: Most likely you are going to get the same response in Curl. I suspect your problem is the values you specified for the parameters. Let me know how you go with it. Goodluck.

Comment: curl does the same, got error 400(bad request). However, I somehow can get it done on postman. my input are the following
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: my_id
client_secret:my_secret
code:code it provites in the url
redirect_uri: url of my heroku app.

Below is the result
{
    "scope": "P",
    "access_token": the access token,
    "expires_in": 2592000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": refresh token
}
It did go through, so I assume something from my end needs to work on?

Comment: So what did you changed to make the postman work? I still believe the error is derived from bad parameter values.

Comment: we have similar problem, how did you manage to work it in postman?

Answer (score 0):

It seems no problem with your access token request.

Can you recheck the `redirect_uri` used by making an authorization request
is same to the `callback URL` registered in the LINE console?

As described in the [Line Login documents](https://developers.line.me/en/docs/line-login/web/integrate-line-login/):

> redirect_uri   : Callback URL. URL that users are redirected to after authentication and authorization. Must match one of the the callback URLs registered for your channel in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error 400 problem. In my case, my redirect_uri contains parameter e.g. mysite.com?action=abc which not work. It accept something like mysite.com/action/abc.